# Tomcat - 2Way SSL on REST services only on some methods

Tags: java, spring, security, ssl, tomcat

I have a Maven Web Application using Spring which exposes some REST services on Tomcat.
Some of these methods should be exposed on 1 WaySSL (https), Others should be exposed on 2Way SSL (https with server needs client certificate).

Is it possible?
If I configure Tomcat with 2way-SSL (clientAuth="true" in server.xml) ALL methods , of course, need client certificate.

Any suggestion?

Comment: is it not possible to have 2 http connectors, one of them with clientAuth="true"? Did you try it? However, you will need to send your rest requests via different ports.

Comment: After some googling ... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153288/is-it-possible-to-have-one-way-and-mutual-ssl-for-same-web-app-same-time-dependi

Comment: Thanks fairtrax, it works and it is much simpler! Just configure 2 connectors on different ports.