# Vertx Server Set Mutual Auth Requirement Per Route

Tags: java, vert.x, mutual-authentication, vertxoptions

I have a Vertx (3.9.x) based HTTP server in which I need to cater to two sets of request paths. First path always expects client certificates (`ClientAuth.REQUIRED`) and another for which client certificate is optional (`ClientAuth.REQUEST` or `ClientAuth.NONE`).

As I could see, only place where the `ClientAuth` could be set is `HttpServerOptions`, and it binds to a specific port, sample code snippet below:

```
final HttpServerOptions options = new HttpServerOptions()
        .setPort(443)
        .setClientAuth(ClientAuth.REQUIRED) // One option per listening port.
        // Set all other server options
```

The Router configuration is somewhat like below:

```
final Router router = Router.router(vertx);
router.route("/required-client-cert/").handler(this::handleMutualAuth);
router.route("/no-need-client-cert/").handler(this::handleRegularAuth);

// Any one of the above routes can work anytime, because ClientAuth is configured in server options.
```

Is it possible to handle this within single Vertx application? If yes, how?

Is there any alternative, while listening on single port?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some more research, I ended up with what is suggested in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33153288/is-it-possible-to-have-one-way-and-mutual-ssl-for-same-web-app-same-time-dependi). In short, "*I cannot vary the SSL configuration based on the URL's path since it is only available after the SSL connection has been established*".

The resolution is that, I can have a another handler at the beginning for paths that need client certificate (mutual auth) and validate the client certificate there, something like below:

```
router.route("/required-client-cert/")
          .handler(clientCertHandler::validateClientCert)
          .handler(this::handleMutualAuth);
```

---

PS: The other approach is configure a different port for listening for requests that need mutual auth. However, in my case configuring another port is not an option.